# my ECMA 6 Promises do not resolve in sync way

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am trying to understand ES6 Promises (and promises in general) but things are not clear for me. I tried to get this code running :

```
var function1 = function() {
    console.log("function 1 has started")
}

var function2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("function2 has started");
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("function2 has ended")
        resolve();
    }, 3000) 
})

var function3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("function3 has started");
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("function 3 has ended")
        resolve()
    },2000)
})

var myFunc = function () { 
    function3.then(function2).then(function1())
}

myFunc();
```

The Output I expected :

```
function3 has started
//after 2 seconds
function3 has ended
function2 has started
//after 3 seconds
function2 has ended
function1 has started
```

The output I get :

```
function2 has started
function3 has started
function1 has started
//after 2 seconds
function3 has ended
//1 second more
function2 has ended
```

Could you explain me what I did wrong on my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind:

- When invoking a Promise constructor, the passed callback function always gets invoked IMMEDIATELY from inside of the constructor.
- Callbacks that you pass to then() or catch() are NEVER invoked immediately.

Therefore, in your scenario, the strings "function2 has started" and "function3 has started" are printed *as the two Promises are construcuted*.

"function 1 has started" is printed immediately thereafter because you directly invoke it from within myFunc(). You probably meant to pass function1 *without parenthesis* like this:

```
function3.then(function2).then(function1)
```

In that case, function1 would only be called at the end (as you expected) once both promises have fulfilled.

I think the sequence of the remaining two outputs is clear, The "ended" messages are printed as the setTimeout callbacks get called.

The following produces the output you were expecting.

```
var function1 = function() {
    console.log("function 1 has started")
}

var function2 = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("function2 has started");
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("function2 has ended")
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
};

var function3 = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("function3 has started");
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("function 3 has ended")
            resolve()
        }, 2000);
    });
};

var myFunc = function () { 
    function3().then(function2).then(function1);
}

myFunc();
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. This is clear. How should I refactor my code to get the output I expect ? This does not make sense to me :(

Comment: Added a version of the code that produces the output you expected. The second promise now only gets constructed once the first one fulfills (causing the timers to run in sequence) - whereas in your version, both Promises got constructed in the beginning (causing the timers to run in parallel).